# Load XML with PHP, pass the XML to browser

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, simplexml

I want to load **XML** from an **external link** using PHP, then pass the XML file to my browser where I parse it with jQuery.

I want to load the xml from this link:
http://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=GDP&api_key=f59d7e0739a5b0745a987b34993bdea7

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Make a PHP function to load the data from the link

`function getXML()
{
$out  = file_get_contents("http://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=GDP&api_key=f59d7e0739a5b0745a987b34993bdea7"); 
    echo $out; 
}`

2- save it in file and name it for example XMLGetter.php

3- use a jquery function to obtain the data from the file and parse it

`$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "XMLGetter.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
            //parse XML here 
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of how to use SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

You need to get that url into a string (simplexml_load_string($loadedString);) and in the end you can render it by:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be being a little daft here....
Why not load the XML straight from the site into the browser?
i.e

```
[api.stlousfed.org] ---> [browser]
```

instead of

```
[api.stlousfed.org] ---> [your_server] ---> [browser]
```

Alternayively something you could to make you life easier in the browser javascript is to load the XML on your server, parse it, and convert it to a sensible JSON representation. Then you could cache the JSON and send that to the browser. It would be smaller file to send, and quicker for the browser to parse and make more sense to work with in the javascript.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ <- work around